# Admob with android non markets

Tags: android, admob

I have this doubt running through my veins. I have created a youtube downloader app. I am publishing this on markets other than Google play store. The latest version of admob doesn'th really let me link the app to the ad. When I search it gives me only Google play store and iTunes suggestions. Does anyone have a solution to link your admob to other non market apps? If so please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't want to publish the app on the play store because it violates their policy, hence might lead to a suspension. At the moment, NO. There's no solution to linking admob to other markets. The Application Visibility and Discoverability troubleshooter provided [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329) pertains only to the play store

You should use any of the ad services below(adversiting ID complaint) if you don't want to publish your app to the play store:

```
Startapp
AppFlood
NativeX
Appia
Epom Market
Airpush
Appwiz
RevMob
MobileCore
AerServ
Appnext
AppBrain
Widdit
MobiMicro
AppKey
AppOptim
StarApplication
Mobicow
Pingjam
TapContext
InMobi
Minimob
```

IMO, startapp is better than admob especially when using their interstitial ads. You can find a list of 2014 top android ad services from these sites http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/ad  http://www.mobyaffiliates.com/blog/a-list-of-android-advertising-networks/

Comment: So is there any other ad services that I can integrate to my app?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you will probably not get approved for admob because of their policy guidelines. Alternatively, you may go for TAPJOY it is the best alternative to admob in the market. Below are some high paying networks:
Topjoy
Mopub
KIIP
Get the full list of ad networks with reviews and payments at: [Mobile app ad networks](http://topadnetworks.com/top-10-mobile-ad-networks-for-mobile-app-monetization/)