# Android app on personal website

Tags: android, apk

I have uploaded an Android app in Google Play and the 1st version went live. On the same day I realized and fixed 1 bug and uploaded the new version but it was rejected by Google saying it violates the gambling policy. Then I read all the gambling policies and I found it hard to accomplish as it requires a licences for some countries...

My question is, Can I host the Android app **apk** on my own website from where the users can download and install it manually? If yes then is there any way the user can directly install the app from my website just like google play store?

Will I still be able to earn from Google AdMob (mediation), reward videos, etc ?

Thanking you

Comment: You can host an apk on your website, people can download and install it-  they'd have to download it first, then  open it in a file browser to install it.  Any type of ad network would depend on the network.  Please note that this is about technically possible- if your app is a gambling app it may not be legal to allow download or to take money in some countries.  Especially in the United States.  Consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

- You can host an Android app on your own website, Android is an open ecosystem. There are also other App stores besides Google Play
- Any APK file can be downloaded from a website and an Android phone will install it
- Most Android phones will require the user to ["Enable unknown sources"](https://www.androidcentral.com/unknown-sources) before they allow the install.
- For AdMob see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165488/admob-with-android-non-markets)

Comment: Thanks for your time! I have read the AdMob question. What my doubt is, I can see the Ads (Test Ads) and also the real ads on my app which is still not live on Google Play. If I host it on my own website or other market place it should work as is or will there be any problem?